# Seminaire Henri Cartan: Eilenberg-Maclane spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Consider [Theorem 1 on page 11-09 of *Seminaire Henri Cartan 7e annee: 1954/1955*](http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1954-1955__7_1_A11_0.pdf). The theorem is about a homomorphism $f:H(X)\rightarrow H_*(K(\pi,n);\mathbb{Z})$, where $X$ is a differential graded algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$ described earlier in the same section. The theorem states that $f$ is an epimorshism, and gives a description of the kernal of $f$ for each $p$-primary component.

It seems to me that the homomorphism $f$ is always an isomorphism, given what the theorem says. Is this really the case? If so, why is it not stated explicitly? If not, could you give an example that f is not injective?

Comment: Please consider editing the question to make it self explanation art to some extent...

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik  The definition of the notations involved in the theorem are rather lengthy so I guess it is better to follow the link and read the original.

Comment: What if some one can not read that language?

Comment: From what I understand, they have written that if you have homology in e.g. $X_0 \otimes X'_p \otimes X'_q$ (for $p \neq q$) that gets sent to zero, for example. Moreover the $q$-primary part in $X_0 \otimes X'_p$ gets sent to zero too.

Comment: @ Najib That is true, but it seems that the $q$-primary part of $H(X_0\otimes X'_p)$ is itself zero when $q\neq p$.

Comment: @Najib What I just said was wrong: For $K(\mathbb{Z}_3,2)$, the homology group $H_4(X_3)$ has a $2$-torsion. Thanks!